# Force close error in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am having a force close problem with my application using ListView. The problem only occurs when I use ListActivity in stead of Activity. The wierd part is that I have another class which does exactly the same thing, but just with another table from the database and it is working fine. I tried to remove everything in my class and just display the view, but I still get the force close.

I found some simular questions on the site, but the answers did not work for me.

Anybody have any clue of what I am doing wrong? - Any help much appreciated.

My xml file:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ListView android:id="@+id/android:list" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 
<TextView android:id="@+id/android:empty" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="No recipes!" /> 
</TableLayout>
```

My Class:

```
public class RecipesAlphabet extends ListActivity {

private GroceryDbAdapter mDbHelper;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.alphabetical);

    mDbHelper = new GroceryDbAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();
    fillRecipes();
    mDbHelper.close();
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
    } 
private void fillRecipes() {
    Cursor recipeCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllRecipes();
    startManagingCursor(recipeCursor);

    String[] from = new String[] {GroceryDbAdapter.KEY_RECIPE};
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.text1};

    SimpleCursorAdapter recipes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.groceries_row, recipeCursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(recipes);

}
}
```

Log Cat:

```
05-26 19:00:23.864: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(401): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
05-26 19:00:23.864: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(401): CheckJNI is ON
05-26 19:00:24.134: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(401): --- registering native functions ---
05-26 19:00:25.454: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(401): Shutting down VM
05-26 19:00:25.464: DEBUG/dalvikvm(401): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
05-26 19:00:25.475: INFO/AndroidRuntime(401): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
05-26 19:00:26.154: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(415): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
05-26 19:00:26.154: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(415): CheckJNI is ON
05-26 19:00:26.394: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(415): --- registering native functions ---
05-26 19:00:27.294: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.aqeel.grocerylisttest/.Main }
05-26 19:00:27.524: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(415): Shutting down VM
05-26 19:00:27.564: DEBUG/dalvikvm(415): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
05-26 19:00:27.634: INFO/AndroidRuntime(415): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
05-26 19:00:27.694: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Start proc com.android.aqeel.grocerylisttest for activity com.android.aqeel.grocerylisttest/.Main: pid=422 uid=10042 gids={}
05-26 19:00:29.274: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Displayed activity com.android.aqeel.grocerylisttest/.Main: 1755 ms (total 257143 ms)
05-26 19:00:34.543: DEBUG/dalvikvm(124): GC_EXPLICIT freed 252 objects / 11688 bytes in 209ms
05-26 19:00:40.393: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.android.aqeel.grocerylisttest/.Recipes }
05-26 19:00:40.454: DEBUG/dalvikvm(58): GREF has increased to 301
05-26 19:00:41.043: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Displayed activity com.android.aqeel.grocerylisttest/.Recipes: 598 ms (total 598 ms)
05-26 19:00:42.453: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.android.aqeel.grocerylisttest/.RecipesAlphabet }
05-26 19:00:42.563: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(422): Shutting down VM
05-26 19:00:42.563: WARN/dalvikvm(422): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
05-26 19:00:42.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(422): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-26 19:00:42.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(422): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.aqeel.grocerylisttest/com.android.aqeel.grocerylisttest.RecipesAlphabet}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
05-26 19:00:42.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(422):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
05-26 19:00:42.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(422):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-26 19:00:42.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(422):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-26 19:00:42.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(422):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-26 19:00:42.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(422):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-26 19:00:42.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(422):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-26 19:00:42.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(422):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-26 19:00:42.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(422):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-26 19:00:42.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(422):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-26 19:00:42.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(422):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-26 19:00:42.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(422):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-26 19:00:42.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(422):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-26 19:00:42.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(422): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
05-26 19:00:42.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(422):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:314)
05-26 19:00:42.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(422):     at android.widget.CursorAdapter.init(CursorAdapter.java:111)
05-26 19:00:42.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(422):     at android.widget.CursorAdapter.<init>(CursorAdapter.java:90)
05-26 19:00:42.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(422):     at android.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter.<init>(ResourceCursorAdapter.java:47)
05-26 19:00:42.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(422):     at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:84)
05-26 19:00:42.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(422):     at com.android.aqeel.grocerylisttest.RecipesAlphabet.fillRecipes(RecipesAlphabet.java:32)
05-26 19:00:42.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(422):     at com.android.aqeel.grocerylisttest.RecipesAlphabet.onCreate(RecipesAlphabet.java:21)
05-26 19:00:42.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(422):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-26 19:00:42.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(422):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
05-26 19:00:42.603: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(422):     ... 11 more
05-26 19:00:42.714: DEBUG/dalvikvm(422): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5728 objects / 343136 bytes in 110ms
05-26 19:00:42.733: WARN/ActivityManager(58):   Force finishing activity com.android.aqeel.grocerylisttest/.RecipesAlphabet
05-26 19:00:42.753: WARN/ActivityManager(58):   Force finishing activity com.android.aqeel.grocerylisttest/.Recipes
05-26 19:00:43.253: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{450e6a18 com.android.aqeel.grocerylisttest/.RecipesAlphabet}
05-26 19:00:44.774: INFO/Process(422): Sending signal. PID: 422 SIG: 9
05-26 19:00:44.827: INFO/WindowManager(58): WIN DEATH: Window{450df0f8 com.android.aqeel.grocerylisttest/com.android.aqeel.grocerylisttest.Main paused=false}
05-26 19:00:44.827: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Process com.android.aqeel.grocerylisttest (pid 422) has died.
05-26 19:00:44.844: INFO/WindowManager(58): WIN DEATH: Window{450e3c80 com.android.aqeel.grocerylisttest/com.android.aqeel.grocerylisttest.Recipes paused=true}
05-26 19:00:44.895: INFO/UsageStats(58): Unexpected resume of com.android.launcher while already resumed in com.android.aqeel.grocerylisttest
05-26 19:00:45.753: WARN/InputManagerService(58): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 422 uid 10042
```

Comment: Are you able to check the LOGCAT log for the exception or error that causes the force close? That could make the problem a lot easier to determine.

Comment: In Eclipse, go to Window->Show View-> Other-> Android->Logcat. and post us what message is displayed in your stacktrace!

Comment: Hi, I am sorry i am a complete noob :D I am not able to view the LogCat since I have not written any thing for it to display - I do not know how. I will check how to do it and get back to you on that when I get home.

Comment: I just opened the LogCat, but it is empty even though I ran the application with the error?

Comment: You should be able to leave LogCat running and connected to your phone or emulator while you run your application.  Even if you haven't written any log statements, LogCat will still have lots of messages from the Android system, including a stacktrace of what caused the force close.  If you don't see anything in LogCat, its probably because it isn't connected to your emulator/phone.  Did you start it while the emulator was still running?

Comment: Okay added LogCat, hope its the right one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the creation of your tables, since your cursor is looking for a column that is not present in the new table:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
```

You need to rename your Primary Key column "`_id`"